# Adding multiple positive values and subtracting it with matching number

Tags: java, list

2. I have two lists, one for positive and other for negative(I converted it into positive to easily subtract). 
   I'm trying to subtract these values with positive values.
3. So far, I achieved to make value zero where both numbers are equal in the list (eg: 10 and -10, or 20 and -20).
4. But, there are some values in the positive list(eg: 3,2,2,1) which can be matched to a negative value(eg: -8) in the list and make all of the values as zero. This is the part where I'm unable to figure out. Please try to help!
5. If input(again getting these values from excel sheet and storing it in a two separate lists, one for positive and negative for other) is : pos= [10,20,46,5,3,2,2,1]  and neg = [-10,-20,-8,-46].
6. The output should be [0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0] since all the values are made zero after finding it's match in negative list.

   ```
   for (int b = 0; b < negativeValues.size(); b++) {
       for (int e = 0; e < positiveValues.size(); e++) {
           pvalues = positiveValues.get(e);
           nvalues = negativeValues.get(b);
           if (pvalues == nvalues) {
               result = pvalues - nvalues;
               positiveValues.set(e, 0.0);
               negativeValues.set(b, 0.0);
               // System.out.println(pvalues+" "+nvalues+" "+positiveValues+" "+negativeValues);
               continue;
           }
           if (positiveValues.get(e) != 0 && negativeValues.get(b) != 0
                   && positiveValues.get(e) <= negativeValues.get(b)) {
               max = Collections.max(negativeValues);
               posVal1 = positiveValues.get(e);
               indexOfPos = positiveValues.indexOf(posVal1);
               // System.out.println(posVal1+ " "+max+" "+indexOfPos);
               difference = max - posVal1;
               System.out.println(difference + " " + posVal1);
               while (difference <= 0) {
                   posVal1 = positiveValues.get(e);

               }
           }
       }
    }
   ```

Here's the pseudo code as well.

```
         i) one list for negative numbers and sorted
         ii) one list for postivie numbers and sorted
         iii)iterate and start with the maximum number in negative list
         iv) check the index of the equal or lesser number in the positive list
         v) iterate the positive list using from this index:
           a) if current positive number 
             1) equal to negative number - nullify and put them in map, go     to next negative number
             2) else if less than negative number - 
               i) get the difference of this positive number and the negative number 
               ii) create a variable for this difference and put it in while loop
               iii) search for the index of the number equal to or lesser to this difference.
               iv) get the second positive number and if is 
                a) equal to difference, nullify all by updatng index of the negative and two positives numbers as NA
               update difference to 0 and exit while and go to next negative number
                 b) else if the second positive number is less than the difference, sum the two numbers and negative number
                and get the difference and update the difference variable with this new value and iterate while loop
                 c) if there is no lesser or mathcing number equal to difference,                                   come out of while and pick the next element in positive list as done in step (v) and get next number and repeat further.
```

Comment: Please, provide example input and output for your problem.

Comment: @Nurzhan Look, its' simple, just find the possible values which can add upto the negative then make them all zero.

Comment: What if `pos=[8,15]` and `neg=[3,5,10]`?

Comment: optimizing addition/subtraction by making if far more complex? can't believe that works...(or: what is the real goal/task?)

Comment: As of now, i'm trying to do it for positive values, ignore the negative values in your case @EganWolf

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I know, believe me, i'm frustrated too. But it is the task where I should be able to match the records in excel sheet and make them zero wherever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a solution is not simple.
You want to find a sum of the combination. For this, you have to use a recursive function.

For example, my solution:

```
static boolean find;
static boolean[] flag;

public static void findNumber(List<Integer> list, int sumNumber, int targetNumber) {
    if (sumNumber == targetNumber) {
        System.out.println("Find Number");
        find = true;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (flag[i] == false && list.get(i) + sumNumber <= targetNumber) {
            flag[i] = true;
            findNumber(list, sumNumber + list.get(i), targetNumber);
            if (find)
                return;
            flag[i] = false;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> positiveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> negativeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < negativeList.size(); i++) {
        flag = new boolean[positiveList.size()];
        find = false;
        findNumber(positiveList, 0, negativeList.get(i));

        if (find) {
            negativeList.set(i, 0);
            for (int j = 0; j < positiveList.size(); j++) {
                if (flag[j])
                    positiveList.set(j, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("PositiveList: " + positiveList);
    System.out.println("NegativeList: " + negativeList);

}
```

I am not sure this solution that you want.